# IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type with OpenAI gym

Tags: python, arrays, types, openai-gym

I'm working on an OpenAI Gym project, and I've been writing some code to solve an environment. However, I keep getting the error that says "IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type", referring to my index of an array, I'm assuming.

I've tried ensuring that my variable "state" is an integer by doing print(type(state)) and it said that it was an integer data type.

My code and the full error are listed below:

```
import gym
import numpy as np
import pickle as pkl

mountEnv = gym.make("MountainCar-v0", render_mode = "human")

q_table = np.zeros(shape = (48,4))
# Parameters
EPSILON = 0.1
ALPHA = 0.9
GAMMA = 0.9
NUM_EPISODES = 500

def policy(state, explore=0.0):
    action = int(np.argmax(q_table[state]))
    if np.random.random() <= explore:
        action = int(np.random.randint(0,2))
    return action

for episode in range(NUM_EPISODES):

    done = False
    total_reward = 0
    episode_length = 0

    mountEnv.reset()
    state = 0
    while not done:
        action = policy(state, EPSILON)
        next_state, reward, done, _, _ = mountEnv.step(action)
        next_action = policy(next_state)

        q_table[state][action] += ALPHA + (reward + GAMMA * q_table[next_state][next_action] - q_table[state][action])

        state = next_state

        total_reward += reward
        episode_length += 1
    print("Episode:", episode, "Length:", episode_length, "Total Reward: ", total_reward)

mountEnv.close()
pkl.dump(q_table, open("q_learning_q_table.pkl", "wb"))
```

The error message I'm getting looks like this:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gym/utils/passive_env_checker.py:233: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool8` is a deprecated alias for `np.bool_`.  (Deprecated NumPy 1.24)
  if not isinstance(terminated, (bool, np.bool8)):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matteo/Downloads/Q-Learning-and-SARSA-Mountain-Car-v0-main/matteos-code.py", line 31, in <module>
    next_action = policy(next_state)
  File "/home/matteo/Downloads/Q-Learning-and-SARSA-Mountain-Car-v0-main/matteos-code.py", line 15, in policy
    action = int(np.argmax(q_table[state]))
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: *Where* in your code did you make sure your `state` was an integer?

Comment: To me a quick glance at the documentation for MountainCar the first argument out is the observation space, which is a 2 element ndarray `[position, velocity]`, so, no, it shouldn't be an integer?

Comment: well I'm setting `state = 0`, so that would make sure its an integer, right? I also ran `print(type(state))` and it outputted `<class 'int'>`

Comment: I did it right after this line:
`next_action = policy(next_state)`

Comment: You are of course *also* setting it to `state = next_state`. Your code doesn't only rely on the fact that `state` starts off its life as an `int`. It needs to stay an `int`.

Comment: You are likely also confusing yourself as you have 2 different variables called state here. You have your top level `state`,  and the local argument to the function `policy`, which also happens to be named `state`. It's not the same. You have also added the check *after* it fails inside the loop, meaning it's your second iteration which fails, and you have no idea what value `next_state` was that just failed inside `policy`.

Comment: so what should I do to fix this?

Comment: I do have another code very much like this that worked pretty fine

Comment: It appears to only do that for this environment, when I do it with `CliffWalking-v0`, for example, it works perfectly fine. I don't understand how it would be different for a different environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt to identify the variable as an integer fails as it doesn't actually check the error, the value is obtained from `next_state`. You should check the variable right *before* it fails, not outside, afterwards.
In fact, you should practice using a IDE that lets you set debug point, and step into the code to follow exactly what value all your variables have at all points in time.

---

Your actual core issue here is that you expect [cliff walking on a grid](https://www.gymlibrary.dev/environments/toy_text/cliff_walking/) and [driving a car up a mountain](https://www.gymlibrary.dev/environments/classic_control/mountain_car) to have any similarity at all; like trying to use a chess engine to control a self driving car.

As you can tell from the documentation linked, the cliff walking has 4 discrete actions, up, right, down, left.
The car driving up the continuous cliff has 2 continuous values, the position along the x-axis and the velocity.

None of your decision making code makes any sense at all when applied to the mountain car problem.

Comment: what IDE do you suggest? I currently use pycharm

Comment: PyCharm works great. Just run your problem in debug mode and it will halt at the point of failure. Or manually set debug points and use the step-over and step-into commands to walk through your code.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Thanks for your help